# Rspec raise_error within context doesn't seem to work

Tags: ruby, rspec

I had this written, and it passed.

```
it 'raises a GitConfigNotFound error when YAML config file cannot be found' do
    allow(YAML).to receive(:load_file)
                   .with(Rails.root.join('config', 'git_config.yml'))
                   .and_raise(Errno::ENOENT)
    expect { described_class::config }.to raise_error GitConfigNotFound
end
```

Then I tried to put it within a context to match my other tests and it failed.  I formatted as shown below.  Does anybody have any insight as to why this is happening?

```
context 'will raise a GitConfigNotFound exception if git config file is missing' do
    before do
      allow(YAML).to receive(:load_file)
                         .with(Rails.root.join('config', 'git_config.yml'))
                         .and_raise(Errno::ENOENT)
    end
    it { expect(described_class::config).to raise_error GitConfigNotFound }
  end
```

It is giving me this output, which seems to be what I want but for some reason doesn't catch it.:

```
  1) GitConfigsLoader will raise a GitConfigNotFound exception if git config file is missing 
     Failure/Error: it { expect(described_class::config).to raise_error }
     GitConfigNotFound:
      Error: git_config.yml not found.
     # ./lib/git_configs_loader.rb:9:in `rescue in config'
     # ./lib/git_configs_loader.rb:7:in `config'
     # ./spec/lib/git_configs_loader_spec.rb:37:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: This might seem rather silly, but have you tried using a `before(:each)` instead?

Comment: Yeah I did try that, but a valid point nonetheless.  I posted my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this is what @PeterAlfvin meant, but I finally foud the answer per another one of his answers! I was using `expect(...)` rather than `expect{...}`.  The parens executes immediately and blows up instantly and isn't caught by the `.to raise_exception`.  Using the braces allows for the `raise_error` to execute the except block and catch the error.

```
context 'when no git_config.yml file is proivded' do
   before do
    allow(YAML).to receive(:load_file).and_raise(Errno::ENOENT)
   end
   it { expect{ described_class::config }.to raise_exception GitConfigNotFound }
end
```

Comment: Another way to solve this problem is to execute whatever you want within an `it` block and rescue the exception.  By doing this you can add other it blocks for any other tests you may want to try.